# Using Braintree for iOS subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, braintree

I am building an app that offers scheduling services for retail/restaurants. I want to use the Braintree iOS UI in the app to let the user pay for the subscription to use the app.  Is this possible, or will the app get rejected because this use case falls outside of the In-App purchase guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reading the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), specifically section 11 (about purchasing), I'm pretty sure it would be rejected under rule 11.2:

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

I think Apple would categorize a subscription as a 'service', and PayPal isn't IAP, so your app would be rejected. Use IAP.

Comment: That was my feeling. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

As of today 2018-09-09, [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines) shows:

3.1.3(a) “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically: magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services such as classroom management apps), provided that you agree not to directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods are not designed to discourage use of in-app purchase.

3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services: Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired elsewhere, including consumable items in multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app. You must not directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods must not discourage use of in-app purchase.

3.1.5 (a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.